# mysql select greatest field value from contiguous rows

Tags: mysql

First time asking a question on here so please be gentle with me :)

I have 2 tables:

- "Master" - a constantly growing log
- "Current" - a single row updated with the latest entry

I am trying to select the greatest "peak" row in a contiguous block (name) of rows from "master" that match "name" in the second table (single row). This contiguous block must be the latest contiguous block in the table.

So the correct result would be:

```
17   | 2016-03-12 23:57:00 | 190    | Tracey
```

Master:

```
id   | date time           | peak   | name
-------------------------------------------------
01   | 2016-03-12 23:41:00 | 201    | Tracey
02   | 2016-03-12 23:42:00 | 107    | Tracey
03   | 2016-03-12 23:43:00 | 103    | Tracey
04   | 2016-03-12 23:44:00 | 195    | Tracey
05   | 2016-03-12 23:45:00 | 134    | Tracey
06   | 2016-03-12 23:46:00 | 144    | Ian
07   | 2016-03-12 23:47:00 | 155    | Ian
08   | 2016-03-12 23:48:00 | 166    | Ian
09   | 2016-03-12 23:49:00 | 132    | Ian
10   | 2016-03-12 23:50:00 | 112    | Ian
11   | 2016-03-12 23:51:00 | 143    | Steve
12   | 2016-03-12 23:52:00 | 165    | Steve
13   | 2016-03-12 23:53:00 | 122    | Steve
14   | 2016-03-12 23:54:00 | 123    | Steve
15   | 2016-03-12 23:55:00 | 132    | Steve
16   | 2016-03-12 23:56:00 | 143    | Steve
17   | 2016-03-12 23:57:00 | 190    | Tracey ----
18   | 2016-03-12 23:58:00 | 165    | Tracey    |   
19   | 2016-03-12 23:59:00 | 154    | Tracey    | latest 
20   | 2016-03-13 00:00:00 | 131    | Tracey    | contiguous
21   | 2016-03-13 00:01:00 | 167    | Tracey    | block
22   | 2016-03-13 00:02:00 | 178    | Tracey ----
```

Current:

```
id   | date time           | peak   | name
---------------------------------------------
01   | 2016-03-13 00:02:00 | 178    | Tracey
```

Update for @EhsanT

I tried:

```
SET @name = 'Tracey';
SELECT * FROM `Master`
WHERE `name` = @name
AND `id` > (
    SELECT max(`id`)
    FROM `Master`
    WHERE `name` != @name
    AND `id` < (
        SELECT max(`id`)
        FROM `Master`
        WHERE `name` = @name
    )
)
ORDER BY peak DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Looking again at this I spose the 2nd table isnt really needed for this query, if the latest id in Master is used.

Comment: Do you need a single query to approach your goal?

Comment: single query would be ideal :)

Comment: If you can get the result I am after with more than 1 query thats also fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice for this answer is to use a `procedure`.

Since I'm not an expert in writing `procedures` you can use the code below, but you should do some verification before running this code, like checking if the name which is passing to the code exists in the `Master` table or if there are other names before this name in the table only this name is in the `Master` table.

Assuming that there are lots of records in the `Master` table and those two above conditions are correct, then this code will do the job for you:

```
select max(`peak`)
from `Master`
where `name` = 'Tracey'
and `id` > (
  select max(`id`)
  from `Master`
  where `name` != 'Tracey'
  and `id` < (
    select max(`id`)
    from `Master`
    where `name` = 'Tracey'
  )
)
```

also I'm sure you know this, but if you want the whole record data, you just need to sort the records by `peak` in descending order and limit them by 1.

So the final query will be like this:

```
select *
from `Master`
where `name` = 'Tracey'
and `id` > (
  select max(`id`)
  from `Master`
  where `name` != 'Tracey'
  and `id` < (
    select max(`id`)
    from `Master`
    where `name` = 'Tracey'
  )
)
order by peak desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This works great, but when I try to use variables instead of stated strings it fails
If I have set the name in a variable, how would I use that with the above example?
Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: Can you please update your post and add the exact query with the parameter/variable you are using which fails?

Comment: The issue I found is due to a tilde ~ in the name field

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from master where peak = (Select MAX(peak) from master where name = (Select name from current))
```

Comment: for the latest contiguous block, you might also have to add something about where the id greater than the max id with the name not current name. Not sure how to code that....

Comment: This code will return the record with `peak value = 201` instead of 190

Comment: I am pretty sure that this will require a LOOP, then step backwards through the ids checking name is same.
I just dont know how to code it